# Should you use outer join fetching with NHibernate and Sql Server 2008?

Tags: t-sql, nhibernate, sql-server-2008, outer-join

On **outer join fetching**, the Nhibernate [documentation](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html_single/#configuration-optional-outerjoin) says:

> If your database supports ANSI or
>   Oracle style outer joins, outer join
>   fetching might increase performance by
>   limiting the number of round trips to
>   and from the database (at the cost of
>   possibly more work performed by the
>   database itself). Outer join fetching
>   allows a graph of objects connected by
>   many-to-one, one-to-many or one-to-one
>   associations to be retrieved in a
>   single SQL SELECT.

I'm trying to decide if I should use outer join fetching in my current project (which uses **NHibernate**).  To that end I'm going to be testing load times with and without *outer join fetching*.  But I would like to know if it's a good or bad strategy on the whole when using **Sql Server 2008**.

Is it generally better to use outer join fetching than not with Sql Server 2008?

How does one determine whether to use it or not?  (other than through performance testing and query profiling)

Thanks

Comment: This is a legitimate question and it's well detailed, why was it voted down?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted and why. It's an issue for me too so: Upvote from me for this one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weird question.
Use outer join fetching if necessary; certain queries will require outer join fetching on some entities.   Other queries won't.  So, if you do not need it, don't fetch eagerly using outer joins.
You can specify the type of fetching for each association when you use the ICriteria API.

It's all a matter of optimization, which can be done afterwards.  I mean: suppose you have an object graph, where certain parts are retrieved via lazy loading, and after testing, if it seems that lazy loading affects performance in a negative way for that specific object graph, check if you could gain something by using eager loading (via outer join fetching f.i.).